# 3ph diode-rectifier with RL load : non - active power

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, power-electronics, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I am studying this circuit. In my book there is an open question about reactive power Q in input in cases 1) L=0 and 2) L=oo
[image]

Well I do  know that Q(Var) occurs when there is phase difference between input voltage and current. I proved by some other facts that in the second case there is a really small phase difference and Q=200Var <<<S.( which I guess could be considered not - important) . But in case where L=0 , is there a intuitive way to explain what happen with Q in input ( i guess is 0 but i can't find a way o put into words)?
Maybe you could also provide me with some facts about active power p in input , distortion power (input - output both cases)

Comment: Great time to use a simulation tool.

Comment: i have one called plecs but there is no tool for power.. so i have to do it bymyself which means that I can't really check myself